# Navigation in the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react"; 
import {
  Content,
  List,
  ListItem,
  Left,
  Right,
  Icon,
  Container,
  Header,
  Body,
  Button,
  Title,
} from "native-base";
    
    
    //Page 1
        
        export function Food({ navigation }) {
                  return (
                    <Container>
                      <Header>
                        <Left>
                          <Button transparent onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                            <Icon name="arrow-back" />
                          </Button>
                        </Left>
                        <Body>
                          <Title>Header</Title>
                        </Body>
                        <Right>
                          <Button transparent>
                            <Icon name="menu" />
                          </Button>
                        </Right>
                      </Header>
                    </Container>
                  );
                }
        
        //Page 2
            
            export class Diet extends Component {            
              render() {            
                return (
                  <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Food")}<---------
                            >
                              <Text>Food</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )} 
            export default Diet;
```

Hey everyone, I'm new to programming and React Native, I'm trying to navigate between two different screens, both screens are on the same page, I tried using React Navigation but it doesn't work, and I'm not sure I'm using it the right way.

Comment: Two screens on the same page? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import * as React from 'react'; import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'; import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'; const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) { return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Text>Home Screen</Text>
  <Button
    title="Go to Details"
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
  />
</View>);}


 function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Text>Details Screen</Text>
  <Button
    title="Go to Details... again"
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
  />
</View>);}

function App() { return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator >
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>);} export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using React Router to create a single page app they have router types that work on mobile

Here are the docs for react native:
[React Router Native Quick Start](https://reactrouter.com/native/guides/quick-start)

Here's a written tutorial:
[React Native Router Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_router.htm)

And a youtube tutorial:
[React Router Native Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYSIT2leZ1g)